# Simple camel cxfrs consumer that consumes json and creates a map

Tags: json, apache-camel, cxf, cxfrs

I am struggling on a simple task. I want to create a cxfrs consumer that simply consumes json.
The json should be converted to a simple map (key->value): I created a simple test:

```
@Test
public final void test() throws Exception {
    MockEndpoint mockOut = context.getEndpoint(MOCK_OUT, MockEndpoint.class);
    mockOut.expectedMessageCount(1);

    context.addRoutes(createRouteBuilder());
    context.start();
    context.createProducerTemplate().sendBody(DIRECT_A, "{ \"ussdCode\":\"101#\",\"msisdn\":\"491234567\"}");

    mockOut.assertIsSatisfied();
}   

private RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from(DIRECT_A).to("cxfrs://http://localhost:8085/ussd");

            from("cxfrs://http://localhost:8085/ussd")
            .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
            .process(to).to(MOCK_OUT);

        }
    };
}
```

The problem is on context.start() i get `ServiceConstructionException: No resource classes found`. I also tried to create the consumer this way (setting binding style):

```
private Endpoint fromCxfRsEndpoint() {
    CxfRsEndpoint cxfRsEndpoint = context.getEndpoint("cxfrs://http://localhost:8085/ussd", CxfRsEndpoint.class);
    cxfRsEndpoint.setBindingStyle(BindingStyle.SimpleConsumer);
    return cxfRsEndpoint;
}
```

This didn't helped neither. So how to create a simple rest/json consumer and unmarshal to a simple map?

Comment: You can use the restlet component that is easier and simpler for REST than cxf-rs

Comment: thanks for the hint. we'll try